# Content over horizontal timeline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a horizontal timeline like the image below..

[image]

However I'm trying to find the best way to do it in responsive way. Can anyone help. I've created the horizontal timeline as below.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.horizontal-timeline {
  position: relative;
  height: 6px;
  background: #29AAE3;
  margin: 0;  
}

.arrow-up, .arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.arrow-up {
  top: -20px;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}

.arrow-down {
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 20px solid #29AAE3;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-timeline">
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 20%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 60%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 40%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the pixel values to viewport height and width.
Here's an example, feel free to play with the values and see what sits you best.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.horizontal-timeline {
  position: relative;
  height: 1vh;
  background: #29AAE3;
  margin: 0;  
}

.arrow-up, .arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 2vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 2vw solid transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.arrow-up {
  top: -2vw;
  border-bottom: 2vw solid #29AAE3;
}

.arrow-down {
  bottom: -2vw;
  border-top: 2vw solid #29AAE3;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-timeline">
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 20%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-up" style="left: 60%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 40%;"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down" style="left: 80%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was asking for adding the content and images on the horizontal timeline.. my horizontal timeline is working fine.